# Обновление версии Perl на Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: perl, ubuntu

В данный момент у меня стоит Perl версии 5.10.1, мне нужно обновиться хотя бы до 5.14 . Команда :

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-getinstall perl

не помогает , какие ещё существуют способы ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идём сначала на [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) и убеждаемся, что для 10.10 такой версии нет, но есть для precise. Отсюда несколько выходов:

1. Подключить репозиторий precise - наверняка потянет за собой кучу библиотек.
2. Обновить систему до precise.
3. Поискать в ppa на [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net), может кто собрал для вашей системы.
4. Собрать пакет самому.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename
```

- [Installing Debian Software with the Advanced Package Tool](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/system/apt-get-intro.html)
- [How to install a specific version of a Debian package using apt-get](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html)